# Android: mediaplayer went away with unhandled events

Tags: android, media-player

I need to get the duration of an audio file for a series of voice announcements that need to play from an app.  I have added the audio files as resources and they do play just fine.  The sample code below actually works perfect for its intended purpose: it does return the duration of the audio files.

Here is the code:

```
float getDurationOfAudioResource(LocationEnum loc, Context context){
    float  duration = 0;
    try {
        MediaPlayer mp; 
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(context, getAudioResource(loc));
        duration = mp.getDuration();
        mp.release();
        mp = null;
    }
    catch (IllegalStateException e) {e.printStackTrace(); logError(25, "TestDescItem:Fault::Could not open mediaplayer object with audio resource.");} 
    return duration;
}
```

Here's the weird thing.  This code is called in a Main activity that prepares the set of audio instructions for a given test.  There are no errors within this activity. But as soon as the Second activity is called, I get a long string of errors on logcat.

```
03-07 13:23:43.820: I/ActionLogger(21435): GenTest_Info_Test #0 successfully created.
03-07 13:23:43.830: I/ActionLogger(21435): GenTest_Info_Test #1 successfully created.
03-07 13:23:43.840: I/ActionLogger(21435): GenTest_Info_Test #2 successfully created.
03-07 13:23:43.850: I/ActionLogger(21435): GenTest_Info_Test #3 successfully created.
<snip>
03-07 13:23:43.910: I/ActionLogger(21435): GenTest_Info_all tests successfully created.
03-07 13:23:47.260: W/MediaPlayer(21435): mediaplayer went away with unhandled events
03-07 13:23:47.260: W/MediaPlayer(21435): mediaplayer went away with unhandled events
03-07 13:23:47.260: W/MediaPlayer(21435): mediaplayer went away with unhandled events
03-07 13:23:47.260: W/MediaPlayer(21435): mediaplayer went away with unhandled events
03-07 13:23:47.260: W/MediaPlayer(21435): mediaplayer went away with unhandled events
03-07 13:23:47.260: W/MediaPlayer(21435): mediaplayer went away with unhandled events
03-07 13:23:47.260: W/MediaPlayer(21435): mediaplayer went away with unhandled events
03-07 13:23:47.260: W/MediaPlayer(21435): mediaplayer went away with unhandled events
03-07 13:23:47.270: W/MediaPlayer(21435): mediaplayer went away with unhandled events
<snip>
```

I've single-stepped upto the end of the Main activity (no errors) and from the first line of the Second activity.  The errors definitely are thrown between the activities.
Also, if I comment out the eight lines of the try block (thus returning only zero) the logcat errors are avoided.  When I restore the eight lines the errors come back.
I've dug through the documentation and searched the web, and I believe that I am correctly constructing, releasing and destroying the mediaplayer object, so I can't see why i am getting an error.
That said, I must be doing something wrong.  Any ideas?

Thanks,

Kevin

Answer (score 231, accepted):

Just put `mp.reset();` before `mp.release();`.

Comment: mp.stop();     
mp.reset();    
mp.release();  
mp = null;

Comment: Didn't fix it for me.

Comment: What this does is it resets MediaPlayer to uninitialized state; [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#reset()). This way you explicitly discard any unhandled event and when destroying object the warning will not show up. I'm not sure though why `release()` doesn't handle this.

Answer (score 63):

The holy five:

```
    if(mp!=null) {
        if(mp.isPlaying())
            mp.stop();
        mp.reset();
        mp.release();
        mp=null;
    }
```

Comment: For anyone using VideoView, this is similar to what it does in `stopPlayback();`

Comment: @vvolkgang Except `stopPlayback()` doesn't call `reset()`