# "MediaPlayer went away with unhandled events" error on Android 4.0 Ice Cream Sandwich on Beagleboard XM

Tags: java, android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I am using Android 4.0 Ice Cream Sandwich on Beagleboard XM. We are trying to play video files from sdcard onto BeagleBoard using VideoView. It is giving the following error after playing for say 30mins or so

> MediaPlayer went away with unhandled events

This works fine on ICS tablets but gives problems on BeagleBoard. Also, in `onCompletion` of videoview or anywhere as such I am not using MediaPlayer object. Didn't find anything related. Some advice would help.

Comment: thats the only warning you get?

Comment: yes i get the above message in logs.On the screen,I get a dialog box saying "Sorry,this video cannot be played" and video stops playing.

Comment: Check this [post][1] It may help you out.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9609479/android-mediaplayer-went-away-with-unhandled-events

Answer (score 4):

just put these after you use the MediaPlayer object

```
mediaPlayer.reset();
mediaPlayer.release();
```

Comment: in what function?, in what callback? can you provide a detail example?